# Не изменяются существующие данные после публикации на сервере

Tags: c#, mvc

Всем привет.
Вопрос будет без примеров кода.
Имеется проект C#Core MVC.
И с ним происходят странные штуки.

При локальном запуске проекта. Контроллер с функциями редактирования карточки сотрудника работает нормально.
Но после публикации проекта на сервер (астра линукс) начинаются проблемы. В виде того, что данные при редактировании не сохраняются в БД.

Добавление сотрудника работает.
Какие-либо другие функции работают
А вот редактирование не возращает никаких ошибок. Функция контроллера срабатывает, но ощущение, что данные не сохарняются в БД.

От чего может быть такое ?
Смотрел данные POST запроса. Там все ОК. А вот что творится на самом сервере не понять.

Comment: "Функция контроллера срабатывает, но ощущение, что данные не сохарняются в БД."
а вы в БД смотрели? а то настораживает слово "ощущение"

Comment: @Lenz да, смотрел. Новые записи пишутся, но существующие не редактируются (локально из под винды редактируются)